# How to add vertices to rectangle?

Tags: inkscape

I created a rectangle with the rectangle tool and I'd like to add vertices to it. I usually double click on the edge to add a vertex but it seems like the rectangle I created is some kind of special shape that doesn't behave like other shapes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a rectangle using the rectangle tool in Inkscape, it creates an SVG rectangle object in Inkscape, which can be seen in the XML Editor as something like `<SVG:rect id="rect1234">`

Here's an example:

[image]

You can turn the rectangle into a regular editable path by clicking *Path > Object to Path*.  This will convert the rectangle into a regular SVG path, rather than an SVG shape.  Then you can add or edit the nodes as you wish.

[image]

Comment: Jebus Christ, Inkscape!

Comment: Which tool did you use to create the animation?

Comment: @AndersLindén I used software called ShareX.